# Randomly chosen student - Mobile phone or Scooter - Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

At a school $2\%$ of the children have no mobile phone, $58\%$ have no scooter and $1\%$ has a scooter but no mobile phone.

We choose randomly a student.

Calculate the probability of the following events :

a) A = the student has mobile phone or scooter

b) B = the student has mobile phone and no scooter

$$$$

I have done the following :

From the given data I have created the following table :

[image]

At (a) $P(A)$ means either only mobile phone or only scooter or do we have to consider also both?

At (b) we have from the table that the result is $P(B)=57\%$, right?

Comment: For $A$ you can indeed have mobile and scooter. For (b) yes.

Comment: In part (a), you have to consider both.  $\Pr(A) = \Pr(M) + \Pr(S) - \Pr(M \cap S)$ by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: So it is $98\%+42\%-41\%=99\%$, right? @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-) @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-) @Surb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) Yes, ‘or’ in Mathematics generally means “either or both”. Alternatively: $$P(M \text { or }S) \\= 1 - P(\text {neither } M \text { nor }S) \\= 1- P(M^c \text { and } S^c)\\=1-1\%\\=99\%$$

(B) $$P(M \text{ and } S^c)=57\%$$

And here's the Venn-diagram version of your table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)